# How to add a clear button in a popup window

Tags: android

I am new to android development. I have created a popup window which is being called on a button click from the main activity class. I have some Edit text field on my pop window. can i clear all these edit text field on the pop up window through a button click? if yes then how? Thanks in advance!! 
Below is what i am trying but it is giving null point exception.

```
 public void initatePopupWindow(View view)
{
    try
    {
        LayoutInflater inflater=(LayoutInflater)  ContactdetailsActivity.this.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        View layout=inflater.inflate(R.layout.popupwindow,(ViewGroup)findViewById(R.id.popuplayout));
        pw = new PopupWindow(layout, 500, 500, true);
        pw.showAtLocation(layout, Gravity.CENTER, 0, 0);
        Button b1=(Button)layout.findViewById(R.id.cancel);
       b1.setOnClickListener(cancel_button_click_listener);   
       Button b2=(Button)layout.findViewById(R.id.clear);

       b2.setOnClickListener(clear_fields);


    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {

    }
}
    private OnClickListener clear_fields= new OnClickListener()
    {
        public void onClick(View v)
        {

        ViewGroup group= (ViewGroup)findViewById(R.id.popuplayout);
            for(int i=0,count=getChildCount(); i<count; ++i)
            {
                View v1= group.getChildAt(i);
                if(v1 instanceof EditText)
                {
                    ((EditText)v1).setText("");
                }
                if(v1 instanceof ViewGroup && (((ViewGroup)v1).getChildCount() > 0))
                    onClick((ViewGroup)v1);
            }
        }
    };
    private OnClickListener cancel_button_click_listener=new OnClickListener()
    {
        public void onClick(View v)
        {
        pw.dismiss();
        }
    };

}
```

Comment: Please post your logcat errors.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you getting your errors on this line?

```
ViewGroup group= (ViewGroup)findViewById(R.id.popuplayout);

ViewGroup group= (ViewGroup) layout.findViewById(R.id.popuplayout);//layout is your inflated
```

I think it might be beacuse you need to use the value you called on the layout inflator.

Anyway, I guess you should do instead: Get a reference of all your edit texts and then clear them one by one. Maybe keep an array of edit texts and walk through them and set their texts to "" instead of checking for the type.

Comment: Thanks for identifying the issue I am getting error at this line only.But the View layout for which I called the layout inflator is in some other function so when i am using ViewGroup group= (ViewGroup) layout.findViewById(R.id.popuplayout); it's showing layout cannot be resolved. Can you please help me with this? Thanks

Comment: try making the layout global variable, or put final on it.